How can I implement a "window" mesh using three.js?
I'm building a small game using three.js as a lab project, and want to implement a "window" element which can see "through" layers. To be specific:
This is layer 0:
layer 0 screen shot
this is layer 1:
layer 1 screen shot
next I went on to try render the two layers together.
If I render both these two layers, the result I get looks like:
both layers screen shot
yet what I'm hoping for is:
desired effect
The code for the camera, blocks and layers are as follows:
// Create camera
const ratio = 130;
const camera = new THREE.OrthographicCamera(window.innerWidth / -ratio, window.innerWidth / ratio, window.innerHeight / ratio, window.innerHeight / -ratio, 0.1, 1000);
// const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
camera.position.set(0, 0, 10);

// Rotate camera
const angleY = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-30);
const rotationMatrixY = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationY(-angleY); // Apply negative angle for clockwise rotation
camera.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrixY); // Apply the rotation to the camera
const angleZ = THREE.MathUtils.degToRad(-45);
const rotationMatrixZ = new THREE.Matrix4().makeRotationZ(-angleZ);
camera.applyMatrix4(rotationMatrixZ);
camera.lookAt(0, 0, 0); // Point the camera at the origin

// Translate camera
const translationMatrix = new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 1.5, 0);
camera.applyMatrix4(translationMatrix);

const blockMaterialYellow = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffcc00});
const blockMaterialRed = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xff3300});
const blockMaterialBlue = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x0000ff});

// Yellow block
const yellowBlockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 4);
yellowBlockGeometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(0, 0, 0.5));
const yellowBlock = new THREE.Mesh(yellowBlockGeometry, blockMaterialYellow);
yellowBlock.position.set(-5, 0, -3);
scene.add(yellowBlock);

// Red block
const redBlockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 1, 1);
redBlockGeometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(1.5, 0, 0));
const redBlock = new THREE.Mesh(redBlockGeometry, blockMaterialRed);
redBlock.position.set(-1, 0, -2);
scene.add(redBlock);

// Blue block
const blueBlockGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(4, 1, 1);
blueBlockGeometry.applyMatrix4(new THREE.Matrix4().makeTranslation(1.5, 0, 0));
const blueBlock = new THREE.Mesh(blueBlockGeometry, blockMaterialBlue);
blueBlock.position.set(-1, 0, -8);
scene.add(blueBlock);

// Create mirror
const mirrorWidth = 3;
const mirrorHeight = 5;
const mirrorGeometry = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(mirrorWidth, mirrorHeight);
const mirrorMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x000000, side: THREE.DoubleSide});
const mirror = new THREE.Mesh(mirrorGeometry, mirrorMaterial);
mirror.position.set(0, 0, -6);
scene.add(mirror);

// Layer configuration
const MAIN_LAYER = 0;
const REFLECTION_LAYER = 1;

yellowBlock.layers.set(MAIN_LAYER);
redBlock.layers.set(MAIN_LAYER);
mirror.layers.set(MAIN_LAYER);
blueBlock.layers.set(REFLECTION_LAYER);
mirrorCamera.layers.set(REFLECTION_LAYER);

I'm a real starter on three.js and would love any suggestions given. Thank you~!

You need to draw your blue box to another buffer and use this buffer as texture for your window mesh. Try to research WebGLRenderTarget.
ThreeJs Doc: https://threejs.org/docs/?q=rendertarget#api/en/renderers/WebGLRenderTarget
WebGLFundamentals Doc: https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-render-to-texture.html
Example: https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_framebuffer_texture.html

Thanks a lot! The framebuffer example really helped me a lot

Yet there is still a pending problem: the "window" in the main scene is not a rectangular shape, making it extremely difficult to apply a framebuffer directly. Is there a good solution to this problem?

Not quite understood. In desired effect window look like a basic PlaneGeometry. FrameBuffer can be used on any type of geometry or mesh as texture. If problem is relevant, can you reveal the issue?
